# поиск нечисловых элементов в таблице Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных, конвертация

есть таблица данных большая. вроде обработал все данные. перевел в числа, но преобразуя таблицу в флоат, пишет что нельзя строковую перевести строку "No" в float. Как найти в какой строке и столбце содержится элемент "No" и как найти где вообще содержится строковое значение
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
all_data.astype(float)
```

выводит:

> ```
> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'No'
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспроизводимый пример:

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,5)), columns=list("abcde"))
df.loc[0, "b"] = "XXX"
df.loc[2, "c"] = "AAA"
df.loc[3, "d"] = "ZZZ"
```

---

```
In [80]: df
Out[80]:
   a    b    c    d  e
0  2  XXX    6    1  3
1  9    6    1    0  1
2  9    0  AAA    9  3
3  4    0    0  ZZZ  1
4  7    3    2    4  7
```

Теперь мы можем вывести все ячейки, которые либо не могут быть преобразованы в числовой тип данных либо те,которые изначально имели значение `NaN`:

```
In [86]: df[df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="coerce").isna()].stack().rename_axis(["index","column"])
Out[86]:
index  column
0      b         XXX
2      c         AAA
3      d         ZZZ
dtype: object
```

Comment: Так не работает - выводит все колонки, где есть числа :)

Comment: Да я то просто тестовый dataframe попробовал слепить )  Автор хорошо бы если выложил, конечно

Comment: @CrazyElf, первую версию ответа писал с телефона, поэтому без примера... Но сейчас уже добрался до ноута)

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку ТС так и не привел воспроизводимый пример, попробуем сами. Генерируем датафрейм, в котором ГДЕ-ТО есть значения "No"

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{'a': str(i), 'b': str(2 * i)} for i in range(5,8)]
data.append({'a':'1','b':'No'})
data.append({'a':'No','b':'9'})
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)
```

Имеем:

```
     a   b
0   5  10
1   6  12
2   7  14
3   1  No
4  No   9
```

Преобразовываем значения "No"во что хотим, для наглядности в 10000

```
def change_item(item):
    if item=='No':
        item = '10000'
    return item
df =  df.applymap(change_item)
print (df)
```

Получили

```
       a      b
0      5     10
1      6     12
2      7     14
3      1  10000
4  10000      9
```

Естественно, все значения пока символьные. Тепер

```
df_float=df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Получили аналогичный датафрейм с типом данных float. И без ошибок преобразования.

Comment: "магические константы" - это как-то не очень, надо смотреть, какие числа есть в df, метод не универсальный выходит

Comment: соглашусь с @CrazyElf. Кроме этого, `df.applymap(...)` - очень медленно работает на больших таблицах

Comment: Так дело в том, что если внимательно прочитать то, что написал потерявший интеерс к теме ТС, то станет понятно, что в его данных кто-то где-то написал "No" как символ того, то либо что-то не так с данными, либо как заменитель  нуля в дихотомических данных, либо по какой другой причине, о которой мы не знаем. И все, что ему требуется - заменить символьную строку "No" на символьную-же строку - например "0". Предложенный мной ответ явно не универсален, но для новичка, коим скорее всего и является ТС - максимально (пошагово!!!) понятный. Скорость и универсальность - это уже "полировка гвоздей" :-)